# What is the default dimension for a user's Twitter's Background image?

Tags: website-design

What are the default dimensions for a Twitter User's Background image?

If I want to upload my own image for my Twitter account's Background image, what should its default dimensions be, as per Twitter's official guidelines?

Comment: The easiest way to infer this sort of information is to right click on the page and choose "view page information" (or properties of page). Typically, browsers will offer a lot of info on "media" loaded with a page, especially the pixel dimensions. Using this method with firefox, I see that the gd stackexchange bg-site.png image is 148x152 px

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Cover image, here is a [good site](http://twitterheadersize.com/) with this information:

> #### What is the new twitter header resolution?
>
> [image: Twitter header size guidelines]
>
> Twitter recommends 1200×600, but it will resize any uploaded image to 520×260 pixels.

If you are talking about the whole page, user background, here is a [good tutorial](http://ct-social.com/twitter-background/). Recommended size on there is 1600px by 1200px. (width by height)

Comment: 1600X1200 still was not uploading to take up the entire background...

Answer (score 1):

**2015 Twitter background/header cover dimensions**

It's not so easy anymore to customize the twitter header because the design has to fit on desktop computer and all the other different devices such as mobile phones and tablets.

Some areas will be hidden or visible on some of them. It's better to not put too much details on it for this reason, and keep the important parts of the design where they will easily be seen on any device.

---

**Twitter has a page with the information on the dimension but you might want to take a look at the templates below to get an idea where to put your graphical elements:**

- Header photo (Recommended: 1500 x 500 pixels, maximum: 2560 x 600 pixels)
- Profile photo (Recommended: 400 x 400 pixels)

https://support.twitter.com/articles/127871-customizing-your-profile#

---

**The 2015 Twitter cover template with the measurements:**

[image: Twitter 2015 header template Photoshop design]

<sup>Source: jennstrends.com</sup>

---

**The 2015 Twitter cover template showing the areas hidden/visible depending on the device it's viewed on:**

[image: Twitter 2015 header template Photoshop design with safe zone for mobile]

<sup>Source: anphira.com</sup>

---

**An idea on where that 1500x500 actually show on desktop:**

[image: Twitter cover design on desktop]

<sup>Source: inlinevision.com</sup>

Answer (score 0):

the size that would accomodate just about all screen resolutions would be 2500w x 1600h pixels (34 inches by 22 inches).

http://profilerehab.com/twitter-help/background_dimensions

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the link is about?

Answer (score 0):

These are comprehensive answers, but they will go out of date really quickly.

Generally speaking, if you want to create images in particular pixel dimensions, you are in developer territory. And if you have a question regarding how to develop for Twitter, there is no substitute for reading Twitter’s developer website.

[Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/)

You can find developer documentation there:

[Twitter Developer Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation)

And you can find specific documentation on the sizes of the images in profiles:

[Best Practices — Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners)

The same goes for Facebook, Apple, Google, and others. They all have developer sites that have up-to-the-minute technical documentation for developers.